# How to find the point of intersection with three equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following equations with three variables $a, b, c$

$a-5b+4c=-3$

$2a-7b+3c=-2$

$-2a+b+7c=-1$

How can I determine the point (if it exists) at which all three lines intersect?

Answer (score 2):

Use Gaussian elimination on a matrix representation of the equations, and you will obtain values for $a,b,c$:

$\begin{pmatrix}
1&-5&4&-3\\2&-7&3&-2\\-2&1&7&-1
\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Writing the equations in matrix form 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -5 & 4\\
2 & -7 & 3\\
-2 & 1 & 7
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\
b\\
c
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\
-2\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then you can check for solutions by using row operations to get the
Augmented matrix to row-echelon reduced form where the augmented matrix
is simply
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & -5 & 4 & -3\\
2 & -7 & 3 & -2\\
-2 & 1 & 7 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Alternatively, you can simply isolate $a$ using $b,c$ from the first
equation, setting this in the other two equations and then solve two
linear equations in two unknowns which I presume you are able to do

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using the row echelon matrix, as everyone suggested. You can also do it using Cramer's Rule.

Let det(S) be the determinant of $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 5 & 4 \\
2 & -7 & 3 \\
-2 & 1 & 7 \end{array} \right)$

Let det(X) be the determinant of $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 5 & 4 \\
-2 & -7 & 3 \\
-1 & 1 & 7 \end{array} \right)$

Let det (Y) be the determinant of $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -3 & 4 \\
2 & -2 & 3 \\
-2 & -1 & 7 \end{array} \right)$

Let det(Z) be the determinant of $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 5 & -3 \\
2 & -7 & -2 \\
-2 & 1 & -1 \end{array} \right)$

Then $a=\frac{det(X)}{det(S)}$
$b=\frac{det(Y)}{det(S)}$
$c=\frac{det(Z)}{det(S)}$

The point does not exist, i.e. The lines (planes, really) do not intersect when $det(S)=0$

Note: How did I get the determinants here? $det(S)$ is simply the determinant of the coefficients of $a,b,c$.

$det(X)$, used for determining $a$, is the determinant with the constants replacing the coefficient of $a$.

$det(Y)$, used for determining $b$, is the determinant with the constants replacing the coefficient of $b$.

$det(Z)$, used for determining $c$, is the determinant with the constants replacing the coefficient of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't lines but planes, but that's fine, the strategies you use to solve 2-variable equation systems are the same as those you use for more.  try, using two different pairs of the original equations, to generate two equations that don't include $a$.  then you can solve those two.

Your best tool for this is something that looks like this:

$$2(a-5b+4c)+1(-2a+b+7c)=2(-3)+1(-1)$$

This sort of manipulation puts you on the early steps of the path to Linear Algebra, which the other answerers seem to assume you already know a little about.  it's not that difficult at this point; they've turned the equations into a table of numbers in relatively obvious fashion and will now use "row operations" to finish the job.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix operation leads to a very simple solution. But, as already suggested by Belgi in his/her answer, you can proceed by succeesive elimination.

The equations being $$a-5b+4c=-3$$ $$2a-7b+3c=-2$$ $$-2a+b+7c=-1$$ eliminate $a$ from the first; this gives $a=5 b-4 c-3$. So, the second and third equations become $$3 b-5 c-4=0$$ $$-9 b+15 c+7=0$$ Now, you see the problem : multiply the first new equation by $3$ and add to the second new equation; you arrive to $-5=0$ ! this makes a small problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that there would be no solution when -5=0?